# Where has my navigation bar gone on a mobile view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently on a MacBook with the display dimensions of 15.4-inch (2880 x 1800) here is a screenshot of how each section of my website looks for my homepage.

**`#app` (section1)**

[image]

**`#section2` (section2)**

[image]

**`#section3` (section3)**

[image]

**----------**

**ISSUE**

Where has my navigation bar gone on my mobile devices? It appears on my computer screen. I have put a screenshot below to show you my navigation bar is missing on mobile devices.

**Please note**
I need the solution to fit on all iPhone devices.

[image]

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wdafatrx/5/)

Comment: Add some code please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in your css:-

```
.collapse {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post! When I implemented this code, the navigation bar isn't centred anymore on the mobile view? Is this the only possible way to do this? I want the nav bar to be centred.

Comment: for that you need to use further css to make it center

Comment: check my edited code and use this. this will be centered now